# PHP elseif or statement not working

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I am trying to define a variable based on the contents of a submitted form, checked against a MySQL database but the preg_match and $variable match will not work together.
They work independently but not together.

I have printed out each variable in every step and proven the data submitted, compared and retrieved is always present but I cannot define the variable when comparing two variables inside the ifelse statement: elseif ( !preg_match("/bt/i",$zip) or $country !== 'Ireland' )

The process is:
form submission -> compare variables against database -> output variable depending on database comparison.

Sample form submission (examples):

fbid (12345678901)

city (belfast)

country (United Kingdom)

zip (BT1 1DS)

This is the (cut down) code causing problems:

```
    $country = $location['country']; //good value: Ireland / bad value: Italy(or empty)
    $zip = $location['zip']; //good value: BT1 1DS / bad value: 00(or empty)

    if ($fbid == $id) { //this works
    $confirmpage = '<h3>Sorry, this page is already in the table.</h3>';
    } elseif ( !preg_match("/bt/i",$zip) or $country !== 'Ireland' ) { //confirm location
    $confirmpage = '<h3>This page is not in Northern or Southern Ireland</h3>';
    } else { //success, page can be submitted
    $confirmpage = '<h3>Confirm Page</h3>';
    }
```

The code not working is:

```
        elseif ( !preg_match("/bt/i",$zip) or $country !== 'Ireland' )
```

When I remove this statement the rest of the script works fine.
If option 1 was negative, with this statement in place, the result is always option 2, even if the form submitted includes BT at the start of the zip or Ireland as the country:

```
    $confirmpage = '<h3>This page is not in Northern or Southern Ireland</h3>';
```

Comment: The operator `or` has not the same [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) as `||`. Try `||` instead.

Comment: @Gumbo: as you can see from the page you linked, both `or` and `||` have lower precedence than `!==`, so this doesn't matter here.

Comment: Your question isn't clear as to what the expected results are.  The conditional you have could be translated to say "Show 'This page is not in Northern or Southern Ireland' if 'bt' is not in the zip or if they did not select Ireland as the country.  I think you have the logic backwards, and both those should be positives?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
elseif ( preg_match("/bt/i",$zip) == 1 || $country != 'Ireland' )
```

Comment: `preg_match` actually returns the number of matches (0 or 1).
Of course you can match `0 == false`, but there really is no need to, and given that `preg_match` returns `false` if an error occurred (invalid pattern, etc), you really should only compare it to `false` using `===`, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is half way there, bad entries and Ireland entries output correctly but correct zip codes returns a bad entry.

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic php page code and copied in your code - then set $country and $zip manually to good or bad values - it works as expected so would suggest it's not a problem with your preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted by changing how the checks are performed.
Instead of: if "condition" or "condition2", I've used ifelse to check the postives:

```
    $confirmpage = '<h3>This page is not in Northern or Southern Ireland</h3>';
    if ($fbid == $id) {
$confirmpage = '<h3>Sorry, this page is already in the table.</h3>';
} elseif ( preg_match("/bt/i",$zip) ) { //BT post code present
$confirmpage = $confirm;
} elseif ($country == 'Ireland') { // //Ireland present
$confirmpage = $confirm;
} else { //confirm page
$confirmpage = '<h3>This page is not in Northern or Southern Ireland</h3>';
```